# Resource TMDIChild not found

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney

I am writing an MDI application. It works fine in Delphi 10.3 + Windows 10, but I get the error "Resource TMDIChild not found" in Delphi 10.4 + Windows 10. What is the problem, and how to solve it? Thanks.

```
  if frmMDIChild = nil then
    frmMDIChild := TMDIChild.Create(Application); { errors occur here!!! }
  frmMDIChildForm.Show;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does the error occurs at compile time or at run time? If it occurs at compile time, are you sure all files are there?

Comment: Solved by refactoring the resource files.

Comment: This is a multilingual program. By removing and adding language to refactor the resource files, I have solved the problem.